# Running Ubuntu LiveCD with another language

Tags: live-cd, system-language

When I loading from LiveCD I see Ubuntu with English but I need Russian. What do I need to do to switch to Russian?

Comment: Hi welcome to askubuntu! Unfortunately I do not really understand what your question is. Are you trying to make a request to developers? Or are you trying to ask an open question in forum style? Askubuntu is probably not the right place for this (see question guidelines: http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask). If you would like to engage in discussions you should try http://ubuntuforums.org or if you are trying to make development requests file try file a bug/feature request over at http://launchpad.net under the appropriate project. Cheers!

Comment: Request to developers.

Comment: What is the request? When you install, you can chose the language - it's the first option... I see no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works, has been working for a long time.

When you boot from a live media, the first screen you see is:

[image: press any key]

after pressing any key you get the menu to choose the language you want to use.

[image: language chooser menu]

All of the above holds only true for legacy BIOS - the Ubuntu UEFI boot menu has not had localisation yet.

Comment: Which button I need to push to get this magic menu, hm?

Comment: @UltraSigmaTel see my updated answer please.

Comment: Oh, thanks. So I wil choose "Русский" and I'll see Russian Ubuntu? Cheers!